# Managing Online Presence in Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Realtime Database, we can easily manage User presence by keeping a reference to a node and updating it as shown below:

```
DatabaseRef presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");

presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
```

If I want to do the same in Cloud Firestore, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: For those hoping for native support in Firestore for *presence*, I recommend starring this issue to show Google your interest: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183581084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use both Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database in the same project. For presence, we recommend you still use the Realtime Database to handle it.

There is a section in the documentation on [how to use the Realtime Database to store user presence in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Comment: How about today (27th May, 2018)? I'm building an app which is used to play an audio file online (only 1 audio file per day for all users at a certain time in the day). In this app, I also need to count total number of "online" users (anonymous) (when the file is played). Please suggest me which one is better for my app, Realtime database or Firestore? Thanks!