# React with Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to switch from realtime database to cloud firestore in my react app.

In my firebase.js, I have a definition of users as set out below.

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = app.auth();
    // this.db = app.firebase.database()
    this.db = app.firestore();

  }  

    doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
      this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  
    doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
      this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  
    doSignOut = () => 
      this.auth.signOut();
    doPasswordReset = email => 
      this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    doPasswordUpdate = password =>
      this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);

    // *** User API ***
    user = uid => this.db.ref(`users/${uid}`);
    users = () => this.db.ref('users');  

}
```

This worked to get users when I was using realtime database, but now I get an error message that says:

```
this.db.ref is not a function
```

Why can't I reference this.db anymore and how do I navigate the cloud firestore docs to find the equivalent?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582975/managing-online-presence-in-cloud-firestore) which recommends keeping the realtime database for some things. Is there a list of things that cloud firestore can't do and is getting a list of users one of them?

I have seen [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) and tried:

```
user = uid => this.db.DocumentReference(`users/${uid}`);
    users = () => this.db.DocumentReference('users');
```

This produces the same error message as using this.db.ref

Comment: You're probably mixing up the Realtime Database API with the Firestore API.  Make sure you're looking at Firestore docs and samples.

Comment: @DougStevenson - the documentation I linked is Firestore - there is no sample for what to do to access the alternative to ref. I've tried collection but it generates the same error when I tried using ref.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding that API documentation.  Try following the examples in the regular documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I'm definitely not understanding the documentation. I have been trying to learn for 7 years and not getting close to demystifying the jargon. I've spent half a day trying to make sense of this link for the purpose I have. I can't get to context. I'll try to find a freelancer to translate the jargon from developer language to english for me so that I can try and get started.

Comment: A suggestion: instead of getting frustrated with your existing code, how about taking a fresh approach to get started. You know you have a */users* collection and in that collection you have at least one user document. Use the code presented in the guide [Get a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) to retrieve a single user. Once you've got that done, expand onto reading all of your users with [Get multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection). Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Jay - I am on my 32nd new approach. I'm trying to actually understand what's happening so that I can learn how to learn. I have not got a single user unless I make one directly in the firebase database. I'm stuck at the step on making one. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: That's what I am suggesting. Go to to the Firebase Console, create a collection called *users*. Then add a document with a documentID of *user_1* and then add a field *name* with a value of *Mel*. Then write the code to access that user. Then, go back to the Firebase Console and add another document *user_2*, then use the second link to write the code to access BOTH users. Once you get comfortable with that process it makes everything much easier.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ref()` in firestore, if you want to access a document you need to use the method `document()`:

```
db.collection("users").add({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Please check the following doc for firestore :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: Thanks @Peter Haddad. That's not what I'm trying to do. I've seen the documents. I can't find a solution to generate the list and individual reference in firestore.

Comment: The Link I shared in this answer, is the official link for firestore